# Trying to calculate power dissipation in Ethernet Isolation Transformer

Tags: power, transformer, ethernet

I have a 10/100Base TX interface with a [100B-1003X](https://inrcore.com/product-finder/assets/admin/images/products/datasheet/M101_RevU.pdf) isolation transformer attached. I am trying to calculate the power that gets dissipated by the transformer itself. The only thing I see on the datasheet is an 8 mA DC bias; not sure how I can calculate power. Any ideas?

Comment: But for what you need this information? Usually you would not consider such a thing, because it is very little, and it might be summed up in the power consumption of the PHY chip as they form an interface as a whole. Even the termination resistors would consume more. And besides, it would have different consumption depending on if the link is 10BaseT or 100BaseTX and whether the link is half or full duplex.

Comment: So I guess that was my question, sorry, whether the power dissipated in the magnetics can be ignored  versus the overall power from the PHY etc